# Heterogeneous vs. inhomogeneous

Tags: latin, greek

I am puzzled about the word "inhomogeneous." Isn't "heterogeneous", strictly speaking, more correct? Do correct me if I'm wrong, but to me, "inhomogeneous" looks like the Latin prefix "in-" added to a Greek word. As such, it sounds a bit like "aquaphobia" to me.